# МАУ ДО СДЮСШОР не заключал(о/а)

Tags: согласование

В какой род нужно поставить глагол в предложении? МАУ ДО СДЮСШОР не заключалА договор (Муниципальное автономное учреждение дополнительного образования специализированная детско-юношеская спортивная школа олимпийского резерва).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Я за *"учреждение не заключало"*. Коли вы уж пишете полное название, то главным становится именно "учреждение". Просто имею некоторый опыт в написании подобных бумаг. Да и еще и то элементарное соображение, что "учреждение" выступает в качестве родового слова, а школа - как название видовое. "Рыба молот плавала/плавал"? Ответ однозначен.

Впрочем, чтобы избежать расхождений, в неофициальных текстах аббревиатуру вполне уместно сократить до "СДЮСШОР" (№ такой-то). Кстати, немного смущает, что у такого учреждения нет "привязки на местности". Таких школ много, надо ж их как-то различать. Обычно эта география или номер попадает и в уставное название.

Answer (score -1):

Согласование тут должно быть в среднем роде: ***"...учреждение не заключало..."***

Если бы текст был не официальный, то главным словом было бы "школа". Это и по смыслу, и по положению (после "учреждение"). Но судя по самому факту использования аббревиатуры полного названия, текст достаточно официальный, поэтому ключевым является слово "учреждение", а вторая часть - независимо от орфографического и пунктуационного оформления уставного названия - рассматривается как распространенное приложение. Отсюда и исходите.

Comment: Я думаю, даже в неофициальных текстах "учреждение" перевешивает.